# How does further hybridization affect fertility?

Tags: genetics, hybridization

Numeruous scientific sites state that hybrids (like mules) are infertile. On the other hand, ligers are known to mate with both tigers and lions and still have viable offspring.

**So my question is: if the hybrid is fertile in the first generation, does further mating with either of the parents' species somehow affect its offsping's fertility?**

For example: if liger mates with tiger let the odds to produce viable offsping be 50%. If this offsping further mates with tiger, are odds the same or are they lower / higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some first generation hybrids[f1] are viable and fertile, but when they mate with each other or back to either parental species[P}, the successive generations[f2] are sterile or feeble.  this concept is known as hybrid breakdown.  This is often seen in hybridized forms of domestic crops.  I am aware that some female tiger/lion hybrids are fertile, but I'm unaware of successful breeding of the f2 generations.  It could be a case of hybrid breakdown.

[Article about hybrid breakdown in rice](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9093864)

[Hybrid breakdown in Cichlid Fish](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0127207)